# How to access windows web service in PHP

Tags: php, windows, web, service

I want to access some of my client's data through a web service. He has provided me below information to get this data in XML format.

http://www.clients-domain.com/erpsync/erp_sync.asmx

User = abcd

Password = 1234

Detail of Functions:

GetAllItemData - Will return all the items selected for web, with their price

GetItemDataByDate - Will return all the items updated between a specific date

GetAllItemStock - Will return updated stock of all items for website

GetStockByItem - Will return stock of single Item.

This web service is on a windows based server.

I dont know how to call above URL in PHP to get this data.
He told me that the return value of this web service would be in XML format.

Also it is SOAP 1.1

Any help appriciated

Comment: `file_get_contents()` would be a simple start. `cURL` is also another solution. Or maybe it's `SOAP` you need to use.

Comment: Use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Answer (score 1):

Since he stated SOAP simple extend the [soap client](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php)

1st establish a connection to the SOAP

```
$soapCon = new Utils_SoapClient("http://www.clients-domain.com/erpsync/erp_sync.asmx", array());
$soapCon->setCredentialsHeader(User, Password);
```

Create a struct to pass variables

```
$struct = new stdClass();
$struct->item1 = $item1;
```

Call functions that client gives you with passed parameters / variables

GetAllItemData - Will return all the items selected for web, with their price

```
$result = $soapCon->GetAllItemData(new SoapVar($struct, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT));
```

GetItemDataByDate - Will return all the items updated between a specific date

```
$result = $soapCon->GetItemDataByDate(new SoapVar($struct, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT));
```

GetAllItemStock - Will return updated stock of all items for website

```
$result = $soapCon->GetAllItemStock(new SoapVar($struct, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT));
```

GetStockByItem - Will return stock of single Item.

```
$result = $soapCon->GetStockByItem(new SoapVar($struct, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT));
```

Soap Client Class

```
class Utils_SoapClient extends SoapClient {

   protected $_targetNamespace;

   public function __construct($wsdl, $options){
           parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);

           // detect target namespace
           $xml = simplexml_load_file($wsdl);
           $this->_targetNamespace = (string) $xml['targetNamespace'];
   }

   public function setCredentialsHeader($login, $password) {
           $header = new SoapHeader($this->_targetNamespace,
                   'CredentialsSoapHeader',
                   new SoapVar(
                           array(
                                   'Login' => $login,
                                   'Password' => $password,
                           ),
                           SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,
                           'CredentialsSoapHeader',
                           $this->_targetNamespace
                   )
           );

           $this->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));
   }
}
```

Comment: So where i will use this USER & PASSWORD?

Comment: Look at the documentation @SadaqatGhafoor

Comment: Thanks David. How do i use those functions? like GetAllItemData?

Comment: @SadaqatGhafoor - Calling the functions with the established object [$result = $soapCon->GetAllItemData(new SoapVar($struct, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT));]

Comment: i got this error in console "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol."

Comment: @SadaqatGhafoor Add this as a first line in the HEAD section of your HTML template

<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding"> depends on how you are doing it but you can do header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); as well