# PHP SoapClient: Object passed is received as NULL in Java

Tags: java, php, wsdl, long-integer, soap-client

I made a php soap client. I am passing a complex object and a string during the soapcall. The object passed is received as null in java but the string passed is received correctly. The class (userGPSDataVisulization)  class has long (userGPSDataId), int , float and string attributes. Can it be because it is sent as simple integer and string from java instead of long and float?

```
class RetrieveUserGPSDataVisualization  {

public $userGPSDataVisulization;
public $StorageMedium='DATABASE';

function RetrieveUserGPSDataVisualization ($userGPSDataVisulization){

    $this->userGPSDataVisulization = $userGPSDataVisulization;
 }
}
class userGPSDataVisulization  {

    public $id=0;
    public $latitude=0.0;
    public $longitude=0.0;
    public $speed=0.0;
    public $timeStamp='';
    public $timeStampStart='';
    public $timeStampEnd='';
    public $userGPSDataId='0';
    public $userDeviceId='0';

function userGPSDataVisulization ($timeStampStart,$timeStampEnd){

    $this->timeStampStart = $timeStampStart;
    $this->timeStampEnd = $timeStampEnd;

}}
    $client = new SoapClient("http://localhost/etc/Layer?WSDL");

//setting dates
$useRGPSDataVisulization = new userGPSDataVisulization ('2014 12 01 00:00:00','2014 12 01 23:59:59');

//populate object
$RetrieveUserGPSDataVisualization=new RetrieveUserGPSDataVisualization($useRGPSDataVisulization);
$params = array(
 "RetrieveUserGPSDataVisualization" => $RetrieveUserGPSDataVisualization,
);

var_dump($params);

try{
$response = $client->__soapCall("RetrieveUserGPSDataVisualization", $params);
var_dump($response);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
  echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```

Through Debugging I came to know that useRGPSDataVisulization object is null when in java but just before calling soapcall in php it shows all the value. Is this due to long datatype in Java?

Thanks

**Update: I have solved this problem**
I have populated the object like this and the object does not receive as NULL. This is another way to call the soap function.

```
$useRGPSDataVisulization = $client->RetrieveUserGPSDataVisualization($RetrieveUserGPSDataVisualization);
```

Thanks to all who answered and guided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing in a SOAP_ENC_OBJECT

```
$struct = new stdClass();
$struct->item1 = $item1; 

$response = $client->RetrieveUserGPSDataVisualization(new SoapVar($struct, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The soapcall takes two parameters. one is the function name and the other is the array, so this code will not work. The soapvar also does not return array. Can you please tell me what advantage I can get with SOAP_ENC_OBJECT?
Thanks

Comment: Oh I thought __soapCall was your function, I'll update my code. The function name is what the client calls and you pass the soap variables into it.

Comment: See how I extend the soap client here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068476/how-to-access-windows-web-service-in-php/27068539#27068539

Comment: SOAP_ENC_OBJECT is just a predefined constant

Answer (score 2):

Rename the following:

```
function userGPSDataVisulization ($timeStampStart,$timeStampEnd){
```

To:

```
function __construct ($timeStampStart,$timeStampEnd){
```

Comment: That won't matter. First one is also a valid constructor.

Comment: @Daan Until PHP 5.3.3 it is, but afterwards it isn't

Comment: True, he didn't specify which php version though.

Comment: @Daan True, but since 5.3.3 has been around since 2010, I hope we can assume he is using a newer version...

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. I am using latest php. I corrected it. The problem I think is serialization. The object passed in php is received as Null in java hence the null pointer exception. Any workaround? Thanks